# Typescript Angular transpiler error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm

I have a working $http service written in Typescript with that the Webstorm Typescript file watcher is complaining about.  Here is the line of code

[image: File Watcher Error]

When I hover over "this" or go to the transpiler window the error is

```
Error:(14, 20) TS2322: Type 'IPromise<void>' is not assignable to type 'IHttpPromise<IScheduleDay[]>'.
  Property 'success' is missing in type 'IPromise<void>'.
```

I don't understand where IPromise<any> is coming from. Any idea what I can do to get rid of this squiggle?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand where `IPromise<any>` is coming from

From the inferred return value of `catch`.

TIP : Split the line `get().then().catch()` into three variables to see the types flow between them